# On AS400, How to call a COBOL program from SQL User Defined Function with structured parameter?

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, cobol

I want to call a COBOL program with SQL UDF in a Select statement. Please let me know if you need more information.

COBOL Data Structure:

```
01  WS-FOO.
    03 WS-FOO-ID                PIC X(16).
    03 WS-FOO-NAME              PIC X(16).
```

COBOL Code:

```
PROCEDURE DIVISION USING WS-FOO.
```

SQL Function thats not working:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ANTHONY.FOO (CHAR(16), CHAR(16)) 
RETURNS CHAR(16) 
EXTERNAL NAME FOO.FOO
LANGUAGE COBOL 
NO SQL  
PARAMETER STYLE SQL;
```

Comment: Do you mean your COBOL program is OPM COBOL/400, or is it ILE COBOL?

Comment: I'm not sure. The COBOL program is run on AS400. There are two lines in the source code " SOURCE-COMPUTER.          IBM-AS400.                     
 OBJECT-COMPUTER.          IBM-AS400."

Comment: If you display the program info [`DSPPGM`] it will show you whether the program is OPM or ILE. You can generally also tell by the source member type being CBL or CBLLE, by convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read section about PARAMETER STYLE in the Info Center page on [CREATE FUNCTION (external scalar)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzcfsce.htm).

If your UDF has two parameters, your COBOL program will need those two parameters *plus* other parameters as described for PARAMETER STYLE SQL.  You may prefer the simpler parameter list for PARAMETER STYLE GENERAL.  With GENERAL, you will compile your COBOL code into an ILE service program.  I will change the lengths in this example.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ANTHONY.FOO ( BAR_ID CHAR(6), BAR_NAME CHAR(10)) 
  RETURNS CHAR(16) 
  EXTERNAL NAME 'MYLIB/MYSVCPGM(MYPROC)'
  LANGUAGE COBOLLE   PROGRAM TYPE SUB
  NO SQL  
  PARAMETER STYLE GENERAL;
```

In your COBOL Data Division Linkage Section

```
01 LS-BAR-ID            CHAR(6).
01 LS-BAR-NAME          CHAR(10).
01 LS-BAR-RESULT        CHAR(16).
```

Followed by

```
PROCEDURE DIVISION USING LS-BAR-ID, LS-BAR-NAME
                   RETURNING LS-BAR-RESULT.
```

Comment: Is that mean there is no way to call the program from UDF without modifying the COBOL program? I'm not able to modify it.

Comment: @Anthony An ordinary COBOL program does not operate like a function in terms of parameters between programs (no RETURNING needed). For a function, it is different. You need to change the COBOL program, or as it is simply not usable as a user-defined function if it is not written as a user-defined function. Or you need to do something else.

Comment: @Anthony You could create a proxy COBOL program using SQL parameters and call the original program from it.

Comment: @JamesA the parameter style is calling for an ILE service program.  If that was merely a wrapper calling the original OPM program, mightn't there be some activation group issues?  I would think it might be safer to compile (a copy of?) the code as an ILE module, and make a service program of it.